# Voltage output of a transistor

Tags: transistors

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft1Lco.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So right now i'm really confused on the voltage output of a transistor. So my common sense tells me that the \$ I_E = I_B + I_C \$. So then the output voltage should be \$ V_E = I_E  R_E \$, \$R_E\$ being the resistance of the circuit after the emitter, and \$I_E\$ would be the input current (\$ I_E = I_B + I_C \$), but this seems impossible due to the fact that you cannot get the transistors will always have the same current and voltage output no matter the model. However, I have seen several different equations for this same problem and am VERY confused as to what equation to use. Can someone tell me the equation to find the Emitter Voltage output? (Sorry if this makes no sense i'm new to transistors)

Comment: In order to (a) avoid misunderstandings and (b) being able to help you it is necessary to use the well known common symbols for current, voltage and resistor.  Did you ever see in a textbook the symbol Er for a resistor?

Comment: Your first three sentences started with "so".  Not only is that content free, but also annoying.  You wouldn't hand in homework like that, so it doesn't belong here either.  We deserve at least the same respect at your teachers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like most things electronic, there's no single equation to plug-and-chug for this kind of thing. Here's how I would approach it:

1. The base-emitter junction of a BJT behaves very much like a regular diode. So under typical circumstances, there is a ~0.7V drop from the base to the emitter. In other words, the voltage at the top of R1 will be about 0.7V less than the voltage at the top of R2. With that information, let's look at just the current path from the V1, through R2, through the base-emitter junction, through R1, and to ground. We're going to represent the base-emitter junction with a diode:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIj8m0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

2. The current flowing through R2 is simply \$I_b\$. The current through R1, however, is the sum of both \$I_b\$ and \$I_c\$ (even though we've removed the BJT's collector pin in this schematic, we will still consider its contribution of current here). Luckily, there's a straight-forward relationship between \$I_b\$ and \$I_c\$ for DC operation:
   $$I_c=h_{FE}*I_b$$
   The range of values of the DC current gain, \$h_{FE}\$, should be given in the BJT's datasheet and is dependent on temperature and current. So now we can use  what we know in Kirchoff's Voltage Law:
   $$5V-(I_b*10\Omega)-0.7V-(I_b+I_c)*100\Omega=0$$
   Substituting in \$I_c=h_{FE}*I_b\$:
   $$5V-(I_b*10\Omega)-0.7V-(I_b+\color{red}{h_{FE}*I_b})*100\Omega=0$$
   We have enough information to solve for \$I_b\$:
   $$I_b=\frac{4.3}{110+100*h_{FE}}$$
   And now \$I_c\$:
   $$I_c=h_{FE}*\frac{4.3}{110+100*h_{FE}}=\frac{4.3}{\frac{110}{h_{FE}}+100}$$
3. Now we have enough information to solve for the emitter voltage... kind of. Since \$I_c\$ should be much greater than \$I_b\$, let's assume \$I_e=I_b+I_c\approx{I_c}\$. Therefore:
   $$V_e=I_c*R_1=\frac{4.3}{\frac{110}{h_{FE}}+100}*100\Omega$$
4. This is not actually the end of the story. Just because the math solves for that value of \$V_e\$ doesn't mean the BJT you're using can actually achieve that voltage. As an example, let's choose the common [2N3904 from Fairchild Semi](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/MM/MMBT3904.pdf). Using an iterative solving technique for \$I_c\$ (remembering \$I_c\$ and \$I_e\$ are about equal), the value of \$h_{FE}\$ in the datasheet is approximately 60. So,
   $$I_c=\frac{4.3}{\frac{110}{60}+100}\approx{42mA}$$
   and
   $$V_e=42mA*100\Omega=4.2V$$
   That means the \$V_{ce}\$ junction must drop 0.8V to accommodate this voltage. Looking at the value of \$V_{ce}(sat)\$ in the data sheet, we see a value of 0.3V for \$V_c=50mA\$, which is close enough for our case here. That means the \$V_{ce}\$ junction of this particular transistor can go as low as 0.3V, but no lower. Since we need to drop 0.8V, the 2N3904 would have no problem achieving that. If, for example, the datasheet had showed \$V_{ce}(sat)=1.5V\$ instead, then we wouldn't be able to achieve the 0.8V drop and highest voltage we could get on \$V_e\$ would be \$5V-1.5V=3.5V\$. Even if the math showed 4.2V, it would be impossible to achieve in practice.

Comment: Nice...I think you should correct all '110' to '10' in your equations though...

Comment: @TisteAndii, I'm not finding the algebraic error you're pointing out. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry...just realized my mistake...its all good

Answer (score 0):

Need an example circuit, since different transistor hookups use different equations and give different output voltages.

For example, for common-emitter circuit, emitter voltage is always zero!  (That's probably not the answer you're looking for.)

Comment: Not with emitter degeneration, but that's still the problem. Bob Smith would have to tell use which he's using.